# my mind is full of.... sentence pattern

Tags: word-usage

Sentence A : My mind is full of thinking problems in my life.

Question : 
Please correct the sentence above, just like a native english speaker would use.

Comment: *My mind is filled with thoughts about all of my problems in life*.

Comment: @JohnQPublic- That just doesn't sound like something a native speaker would say in conversation.

Comment: Yugi, when you are asking questions about sentences, please be sure to identify what you specifically think might be wrong with it. "Please correct this sentence" is on acceptable on ELL. Please tell us what you think is incorrect, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erm... i would say:

`My mind is filled with all the problems in my life`
`My mind is full with all my problems in life`

When you specify mind, you're implying thoughts.

---

*Correct me if i am wrong*

Comment: I completely agree that explicitly using *thinking* here is somewhat "unidiomatic" (Google Books has almost 10,000 instances of *mind was full of thoughts*, but only one *mind was full of thinking*). You're also quite right that in OP's context, *filled **with*** is far more common than either of those. The fourth permutation *(filled **of**)* isn't and never was used by *any* competent speakers, so far as I know.

Comment: I think this *is filled* is probably what the asker is driving at here.

Answer (score 1):

The native, mostly idiomatic expression is

> my mind is full of *noun expression*.

In your case:

> My mind is full of problems in my life.

Often the noun will be a mass noun.

> A weekend of fishing, then cleaning caught fish, cooking fish, pickling, freezing, and in the end eating so much my stomach is about to burst. Then a night of dreaming about fish. My mind is full of fish.

Sometimes, humorously, a singular noun is used as if it was a mass noun.

> After watching an 8-hour marathon of *My Little Pony*, my mind is full of pony.

Comment: I'd accept "my mind is full of problems", but "in my life" sounds weird to me.  The speaker just specified "my mind" as the thing that's full, and narrowing the scope to "in my life" doesn't make any sense to me.  I like your pony and fish examples, though.  (I suppose it would be fine if I parsed "problems in my life" as the object of the preposition "of", but it's difficult to get my brain to parse it that way.)

Comment: @snailboat: I wonder if `problems with my life` or `my life problems` would work.

Comment: @snailboat I agree that the *in my life* is troublesome. I prefer moving *my* in front of *problems* though. Also, to me, I think it need at least one more noun (thoughts). At least that's what's bothering me. *My mind is filled with/consumed by thoughts of all my problems/troubles in/with life*.

Answer (score 0):

> My mind is full of thinking problems in my life.

Here *thinking* is used as an adjective and qualifies the word *problems* i.e. your problems themselves have consciousness and are able to think. I imagine this is probably not what you want to say. 
I mention it because it is important to realize ***why*** a certain sentence structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The exact thought you are trying to express is a bit unclear.  This is a slightly different interpretation than some of the other answers here.

> I don't have time to think about anything but all the problems in my life.

Comment: I don't think that quite expresses the asker's thoughts. I think s/he's more trying to express a sense of being consumed by thoughts. At least that was my interpretation. This seems *slightly* too weak for that.